# Base conversion between 2 numbers

Tags: haskell

I am in trouble creating an haskell function which convert a Int from base 10 to base 8 without the use of recursion.
all library functions allowed

the recursive version I have in mind uses 'div' and 'mod', but without recursion I have no idea.
I hope anyone has any idea how to make it work

edit:
I know how the foldr work in principle but I can't still write the function down, especially because I know the foldr produces one result number, but I need every intermediate result of 'mod'. foldr ('mod') 8 [????].

Comment: likely they want you to use a higher order function like `unfoldr` which does the recursion for you.

Comment: Can you post your recursive version?

Comment: Note that an `Int` value is *not* in base 10 by any means. If anything, the underlying hardware representtation is in base 2. You probably mean you want to generate an octal character string from the `Int` value.

Answer (score 3):

Iteration in Haskell is done through recursion, but that does not mean you need to write the recursion yourself.

Likely they want you to use a higher-order function like [**`unfoldr :: (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:unfoldr) that will implement the recursion for you.

You thus can use `unfoldr` where you pass a function `b -> Maybe (a, b)` as first parameter that produces a `Just (y, x)` where the `x` is the value for the next iteration, and the `y` the "emitted" value.

Comment: I know how the foldr work in principle but I can't still write the function down, especially because I know the foldr produces one result number, but I need every intermediate result of 'mod'. foldr ('mod') 8 [????]. maybe it's a foldr inside a foldr. I am far away from a usable idea. I know it's not fair but knowing the solution sometimes is better. thank you

Comment: @J.G.: but this is not `foldr`, but `unfoldr`, the opposite: `undfoldr f x` will call `f x`, if it produces like `Just (2, 3)`, it will emit `2` (so the list will start with `2`) and continue with `f 3`, until `f` returns a `Nothing`.